# C Seg Fault and Core Dump when trying to free pointer and close file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to read from a file to make a linked list of movies. At the end of the read file function when I try and free the line pointer and close the file I get a seg fault and core dump. Both the freeing and file closing are causing problems. Do I need any libraries? the fopen works just fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct movie {
    char *title;
    char **languages;
    int year;
    double rating;
    struct movie *next;
};

struct movie *read_file(const char *filename);
struct movie *create_movie(const char *title, const char **languages, int year, double rating);
void append_movie(struct movie *head, struct movie *new_movie);
void free_movie(struct movie *movie);

int main() {
    const char *filename = "movies_sample_1.csv";
    struct movie *head = read_file(filename);

    while (head != NULL) {
        struct movie *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free_movie(temp);
    }

    return 0;
}

struct movie *read_file(const char *filename) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct movie *head = NULL;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t nread;

    if ((nread = getline(&line, &len, file)) == -1) {
        perror("Error reading header");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1) {
        char *title = strtok_r(line, ",", &line);
        char *year_str = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &line);
        char *languages_str = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &line);
        char *rating_str = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &line);


        int year = atoi(year_str);
        double rating = atof(rating_str);

        const char *languages[10];
        int language_count = 0;
        char *language = strtok_r(languages_str, ";[]", &languages_str);

        while (language != NULL) {
            languages[language_count++] = language;
            language = strtok_r(NULL, ";[]", &languages_str);
        }

        languages[language_count] = NULL;

        struct movie *new_movie = create_movie(title, languages, year, rating);

        if (head == NULL) {
            head = new_movie;
        } else {
            append_movie(head, new_movie);
        }
    }

    // if (line != NULL) {
    //     free(line);
    // }

    //fclose(file);
    return head;
}

struct movie *create_movie(const char *title, const char **languages, int year, double rating) {
    struct movie *new_movie = (struct movie *)malloc(sizeof(struct movie));
    if (new_movie == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    new_movie->title = strdup(title);
    if (new_movie->title == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    new_movie->year = year;
    new_movie->rating = rating;

    int num_languages = 0;
    while (languages[num_languages] != NULL) {
        num_languages++;
    }

    new_movie->languages = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (num_languages + 1));
    if (new_movie->languages == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_languages; i++) {
        new_movie->languages[i] = strdup(languages[i]);
        if (new_movie->languages[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Memory allocation failed");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    new_movie->languages[num_languages] = NULL;
    new_movie->next = NULL;
    return new_movie;
}

void append_movie(struct movie *head, struct movie *new_movie) {
    struct movie *current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = new_movie;
}

void free_movie(struct movie *movie) {
    free(movie->title);

    for (int i = 0; movie->languages[i] != NULL; i++) {
        free(movie->languages[i]);
    }

    free(movie->languages);
    free(movie);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply make a linked list of 'n' languages (like making a linked list of movies)? No messing around with NULL marking the end of a finite array (that could easily be overflowing...)

Comment: "Sex, Lies, and Videotape"... One movie title that even includes an Oxford comma... `strtok_r()` isn't a robust enough technique to parse any given CSV...

Comment: @Fe2O3 lol its a school assignment doesn't need to be that good

Comment: @ahmed oh believe me, you'd be surprised the length professors and TAs go to try and break your code for school assignments. Besides, a comma in a movie title isn't really something too out of the ordinary so I would personally account for at least that possibility

Comment: @JohnDoe thanks for the ideas would you guys know why I get a seg fault when I try and close the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be more problems but here is at least one...

`getline` will allocate dynamic memory for `line`. You must free that memory later by calling `free(line)`. In order to do that you must make sure that `line` isn't changed, i.e. the value `line` got from `getline` is the value to pass to `free`.

However, you do

```
    char *title = strtok_r(line, ",", &line);
    char *year_str = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &line);
    char *languages_str = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &line);
    char *rating_str = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &line);
```

so the value of `line` may/will be changed and `free(line)` will (most likely) fail.

Solution: Use another char pointer for `strtok_r` state.

Comment: The solution I found was to duplicate the line for each while loop iteration as so **char *line_copy = strdup(line);** and then read the content of the line from this duplicate. At the end of the readFile func I free the original line. In doing so the free doesnt fail.